# Why null in JavaScript is greater than -1?

Tags: javascript, logic

I recently came to know that `null > -1` is true in javascript but did not find the answer why. So can someone please explain why?

[image]

Comment: because of the coercion to a number of `null` which is `0`.

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators

Comment: What *should* it be? If you expect this to not be true, `null` would have to behave like `-Infinity` (smaller than any number) or `NaN` (any comparison is always false), which also wouldn't make a lot of sense. I'd accept an `IncompatibleTypeException` as alternative correct outcome, but Javascript doesn't throw exceptions from comparison operations by design…

Comment: @NinaScholz But ```null === 0``` is false ```null < 0``` is also false

Comment: `null` has not the same type of `0`. `null` is an object and `0` a number.